# How to save the result of a mysql request in ReactJs?

Tags: mysql, reactjs, express

I have a code in ReactJs which is just a SELECT. The request works fine but I wanna save its result into a variable (or something like this). How do I do this?

```
    const data;

    async function selecionaSubsistemas() {
        return Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/api/selecionaSubsistemas", {
        }).then((response)=>{
        });
    }
  
    const getData = async() => {
        data = await selecionaSubsistemas();
    };
  
    console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can save it as `state`

> **state in react**: an object of a set of observable properties that control the behavior of the component

with using React Hook, you should do this way:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  ...

      .then((response)=>{
          setData(response.data) //so you access to the data with `data` variable.
        });
```